# Obtengo valor null de Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-intent, null

Activity 1 (MainActivity): Clásica pantalla en la que se ingresan datos.

Activity 2 (confir): Recibo los datos y los imprime en pantalla para pedir confirmación.

Usando el Debug corroboro que los datos son enviados de la Activity 1 a la 2, el obj Bundle es correctamente creado pero cuando intento crear los String que usan los datos del Bundle, solo recibo null o unas raras descripciones.

Y aún más raro, ni siquiera muestra el nombre que debería ir arriba de la fecha de nacimiento.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button boton;
DatePicker fecha;
TextInputLayout nombre2;
TextInputLayout telefono2;
TextInputLayout email2;
TextInputLayout descripcion2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);
    fecha = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.fecha1);
    nombre2 = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    telefono2 = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.telefono);
    email2 = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.email);
    descripcion2 = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.descripion);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, confir.class);
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pnombre), nombre2.getEditText().getText());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.ptelefono), telefono2.getEditText().getText());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pemail), email2.getEditText().getText());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pdescripcion), descripcion2.getEditText().getText());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.paño), fecha.getYear());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pmes), fecha.getMonth());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pdia), fecha.getDayOfMonth());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
public class confir extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confir);

    Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();
    String nombre = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pnombre));
    String telefono = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.ptelefono));
    String email = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pemail));
    String descripcion = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pdescripcion));
    String año = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.paño));
    String mes = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pmes));
    String dia = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pdia));

    TextView cnombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_nombre);
    TextView cfecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_fecha);
    TextView ctelefono = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_telefono);
    TextView cemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_email);
    TextView cdescripcion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_descripcion);
    Button boton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton2);

    cnombre.setText(nombre);
    cfecha.setText("Fecha de nacimiento: " + dia + "/" + mes + "/" + año);
    ctelefono.setText(("Tel: ") + telefono);
    cemail.setText("Email: " + cemail);
    cdescripcion.setText("Descripcion: " + cdescripcion);

    boton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

[image: Activity 2]

Comment: Cuando usas EditText, hacer `editText.getText()` te devuelve un objeto de tipo `Editable` si no recuerdo mal. Te falta añadir un `.toString()` para obtener el valor del texto

Comment: El '.toString()' lo hago en la segunda Activity cuando creo los String que van a ser mostrados en pantalla:
    Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();
        String nombre = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pnombre));

No es lo mismo?

Comment: No, no es lo mismo. Lo que te está diciendo @Benito-B es que para extraer el texto de un `EditText` como un `String` tienes que ejecutar la función `toString()` del objeto retornado por `getText()` (que como ves no es un `String`). Tienes que hacer: `objetoEditText.getText().toString()`, y eso sí te retorna un `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios detalles, el primero es que **al usar el `DatePicker`, debes primeramente almacenar sus valores en variables para poder enviarlos**, por ejemplo define 3 variables para almacenar año, mes y día y de esta forma puedes enviarlos sin problema:

```
String dpYear, dMonth, dDayOfMonth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);
    fecha = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.fecha1);
    nombre2 = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    telefono2 = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.telefono);
    email2 = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.email);
    descripcion2 = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.descripion);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Asigna valores.
            dpYear = String.valueOf(fecha.getYear());
            dMonth = String.valueOf(fecha.getMonth());
            dDayOfMonth = String.valueOf(fecha.getDayOfMonth());

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, confir.class);
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pnombre), nombre2.getEditText().getText());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.ptelefono), telefono2.getEditText().getText());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pemail), email2.getEditText().getText());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pdescripcion), descripcion2.getEditText().getText());
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.paño), dpYear /*fecha.getYear()*/);
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pmes), dMonth /*fecha.getMonth()*/);
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pdia), dDayOfMonth /*fecha.getDayOfMonth()*/);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Ahora para recibirlos veo que estas obteniendo este tipo de valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se debe a que estas imprimiendo en realidad la vista, debes tener cuidado con las variables que usas, realiza este cambio:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confir);

    Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();
    String nombre = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pnombre));
    String telefono = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.ptelefono));
    String email = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pemail));
    String descripcion = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pdescripcion));
    String año = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.paño));
    String mes = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pmes));
    String dia = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pdia));

    TextView cnombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_nombre);
    TextView cfecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_fecha);
    TextView ctelefono = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_telefono);
    TextView cemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_email);
    TextView cdescripcion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c_descripcion);
    Button boton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton2);

    cnombre.setText(nombre);
    cfecha.setText("Fecha de nacimiento: " + dia + "/" + mes + "/" + año);        
    ctelefono.setText(("Tel: ") + telefono);

    //*Realiza aquí este cambio.
    //cemail.setText("Email: " + cemail);
    //cdescripcion.setText("Descripcion: " + cdescripcion
    cemail.setText("Email: " + email);
    cdescripcion.setText("Descripcion: " + descripcion);

    boton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```